# How do I compile & install the newest version of Transmission?

Tags: 10.04, gtk, compiling, transmission, make

I'm trying to install Transmission 2.51 on Ubuntu 10.04. Compiling the source goes fine, but I can't seem to get it to compile the GUI as well. This is the configure output:

```
Configuration:

   Source code location:                              .
   Compiler:                                          g++

   Build libtransmission:                             yes
      * optimized for low-resource systems:           no
      * µTP enabled:                                  yes

   Build Command-Line client:                         yes

   Build GTK+ client:                                 no (GTK+ none)
      * libappindicator for an Ubuntu-style tray:     no

   Build Daemon:                                      yes

   Build Mac client:                                  no
```

How do I get it to build the GTK+ client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `./configure` file reveals the following:

```
##
##
##   MANDATORY for the GTK+ client
##
##

GTK2_MINIMUM=2.22.0

GTK3_MINIMUM=3.2.0

GLIB_MINIMUM=2.28.0

GIO_MINIMUM=2.26.0
```

Looking at the [lucid packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&searchon=names&keywords=libgtk2.0), GTK2 currently is 2.20.  Since GTK2 is so fundamental to all of Lucid applications, I would not recommend that you try to uplift your GTK version (it will require a major recompile of all sorts of stuff).

You cannot simply reduce those minimum version values - I've tried... the compilation will fail because the code requires the newer GTK libraries.

If you want a relatively newer version (v2.33) that will work with Lucid, can I suggest this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install transmission
```

Run `transmission-gtk` reveals:

[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is that anything newer than Transmission 2.33 isn't compatible with the stable releases of Ubuntu, so I can't have the features I need from Transmission 2.51 without upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu which will most probably break most of the other applications I'm using. That's just **** great

Comment: ... correct ... the developers like playing with newer shiny stuff... hence older stable OS's can only be upgraded to the latest version if the developers themselves have decided they support it.  In this case - they only support GTK+2.22 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the package **libgtk-3-dev**.

Otherwise the compiling process will break with this message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.2.0
                              glib-2.0 >= 2.32.0
                              gio-2.0 >= 2.26.0,
                              gmodule-2.0 >= 2.32.0
                              gthread-2.0 >= 2.32.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

You just need to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting latest transmission-gtk to build and run on Ubuntu 10.04 is possible, but hard and cumbersome due to the gtk dependancy. Getting it themed right may also be messy. You might want to consider just going with the daemon, and control it with the webui and/or one of the many [third-party rpc clients](http://www.transmissionbt.com/resources/). There's a PPA which currently has version 2.60, for Ubuntu 10.04, of all the clients except the gtk client: [ppa:transmissionbt/nogtk](https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/nogtk)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the required development tools with this command

> sudo apt-get install build-essential automake autoconf libtool pkg-config intltool libcurl4-openssl-dev libglib2.0-dev libevent-dev libappindicator-dev

Then compile with

> tar xvjf transmission-2.51.tar.bz2
>   cd transmission-2.51
>   ./configure -q --with-gtk --enable-daemon --with-inotify --enable-nls && make -s
>   su  
>   make install

Comment: E: Couldn't find package libminiupnpc-dev

Comment: dont install it you will already be having `libupnp3` & `libupnp-dev `... edited my answer

Comment: Still says "Build GTK+ client: no (GTK+ none)". Additionally, this warning appears: "configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-gtk, --enable-libnotify"

Comment: srry wrong argument... again edited

Comment: configure: error: "GTK+ not found!"

Comment: instead of all this just run the autogen.sh file in the terminal and see

Comment: Running autogen.sh also outputs "Build GTK+ client: no (GTK+ none)". Are you sure Transmission 2.51 can even be installed on Ubuntu 10.04?